# Synchronization of R file with code causing ClassCastException

Tags: android, r.java-file

I deployed a new version of one of my apps yesterday. I had a couple of ClassCastExceptions reported on the market dashboard this morning. The exceptions were happening because my java code was using findViewById to retrieve an element which I was casting to a Button. This was raising an exception as the element retrieved was in fact a LinearLayout. To troubleshoot this I took a copy of my latest generated R file from eclipse and saved it in a text file. I cleaned the project and took a new copy of R and compared them. The ids associated with some of the widgets were indeed different. The id of the button had been the id of the LinearLayout. I assume that deploying this cleaned project to production will now fix this issue. 
My question is how did my code run locally with this disconnect between the R file and the xml? I will make sure to run a clean in future before I deploy, but this seems like a bug.

Comment: May be you did not open that specific part of application that contain the conflict.

Comment: The issue was on my Dashboard Activity. Everything goes through this, so I had opened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how did my code run locally with this disconnect between the R file and the xml?

Your problem wasn't with a "disconnect between the R file and the xml".

Your problem was with a disconnect between "the R file" and the rest of your code.

The values in `R.java` are marked static final. Hence, the actual numbers are inlined into the bytecode of any class referencing those values. Sometimes Android updates the `R.java` file but does not wipe out the pre-compiled classes in your project that referenced the old `R.java` file. Any values that changed in `R.java` will now be out of sync with those previously-compiled classes. Depending on which ones those are, you will encounter various sorts of errors, such as a `ClassCastException` as a result of a `findViewById()` call.

In terms of how you were able to run it locally, the only answer is that you were running a different APK than what you uploaded.

> I will make sure to run a clean in future before I deploy

This is an excellent idea. If you elect to do a command-line build for your production APK generation, just add `clean` into your ant target list.

> but this seems like a bug

It is certainly an annoying limitation of the build tools. Note that this affects the command-line build process as well. Back in the halcyon days of yore, when I didn't use Eclipse, I would just do a `clean` on every build (nowadays, that would be `ant clean debug install`).

Comment: I often stumble upon this issues with sometimes funny results. Background has now the background of a button... sometimes funny, but often annoying :)